# ByRef Local Variable using Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm having trouble with selecting only part of a collection and passing it by reference.

So I have a custom class EntityCollection which is , who guessed, a collection of entities. I have to send these entities over HTTPSOAP to a webservice.

Sadly my collection is really big, let's say 10000000 entities, which throws me an HTTP error telling me that my request contains too much data.

The method I am sending it to takes a Reference of the collection so it can further complete the missing information that is autogenerated upon creation of an entity.

My initial solution:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ecCreate.Count - 1 Step batchsize
                Dim batch As EntityCollection = ecCreate.ToList().GetRange(i, Math.Min(batchsize, ecCreate.Count - i)).ToEntityCollection()
                Q.Log.Write(SysEnums.LogLevelEnum.LogInformation, "SYNC KLA", "Creating " & String.Join(", ", batch.Select(Of String)(Function(e) e("nr_inca")).ToArray()))
                Client.CreateMultiple(batch)
            Next
```

ecCreate being an EntityCollection.

What I forgot was that using ToList() and ToEntityCollection() (which I wrote) it creates a new instance...

At least ToEntityCollection() does, idk about LINQ's ToList()...

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToEntityCollection(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of Entity)) As EntityCollection
    Dim ec As New EntityCollection()
    'ec.EntityTypeName = source.FirstOrDefault.EntityTypeName
    For Each Entity In source
        ec.Add(Entity)
    Next
    Return ec
End Function
```

Now, I don't imagine my problem would be solved if I change ByVal to ByRef in ToEntityCollection(), does it?

So how would I actually pass just a part of the collection byref to that function?

Thanks

**EDIT after comments:**

@Tim Schmelter it is for a nightly sync operation, having multiple selects on the database is more time intensive then storing the full dataset.

@Craig Are you saying that if i just leave it as an IEnumerable it will actually work? After all i call ToArray() in the createmultiple batch anyway so that wouldn't be too much of a problem to leave out...

@NetMage you're right i forgot to put in a key part of the code, here it is:

```
Public Class EntityCollection
    Implements IList(Of Entity)

    '...
    Public Sub Add(item As Entity) Implements ICollection(Of Entity).Add
        If IsNothing(EntityTypeName) Then
            EntityTypeName = item.EntityTypeName
        End If
        If EntityTypeName IsNot Nothing AndAlso item.EntityTypeName IsNot Nothing AndAlso item.EntityTypeName <> EntityTypeName Then
            Throw New Exception("EntityCollection can only be of one type!")
        End If
        Me.intList.Add(item)
    End Sub
```

I Think that also explains the List thing... (BTW vb or c# don't matter i can do both :p)

**BUT:** You got me thinking properly:

```
Public Sub CreateMultiple(ByRef EntityCollection As EntityCollection)
    '... do stuff to EC
    Try
        Dim ar = EntityCollection.ToArray()
        Binding.CreateMultiple(ar) 'is also byref(webservice code)
        EntityCollection.Collection = ar 'reset property, see below
    Catch ex As SoapException
        Raise(GetCurrentMethod(), ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

And the evil part( at least i think it is) :

```
Friend Property Collection As Object
    Get
        Return Me.intList
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        Me.Clear()
        For Each e As Object In value
            Me.Add(New Entity(e))
        Next
    End Set
End Property
```

Now, i would still think this would work, since in my test if i don't use Linq or ToEntityCollection the byref stuff works perfectly fine. It is just when i do the batch thing, then it doesn't... I was guessing it could maybe have to do with me storing it in a local variable?

Thanks already for your time!

Anton

Comment: Why you select 10000000 records from the database? Where you want to show them? Who will ever look at all? Use a `Where` to reduce number of records or use database pagination.

Comment: Why are you converting it into a collection, instead of leaving it as an `IEnumerable(Of Entity)`?  If you want to pass part of a collection, there are several methods available in Linq that will do that, depending on what sort of subset you want.  `ByVal` vs. `ByRef` is a bit of a red herring when you work with object types; in either case, within .NET, only a reference to the object is passed.  The difference is that `ByRef` allows the called routine to make the parent routine's reference point to a different object.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't show that `ToEntityCollection` creates a new `Entity`. You leave out to much code to know what is happening. Why not use `List<Entity>` instead?

Comment: I edited the post with keeping in mind your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was replacing the references of Entity in my local batch, instead of in my big collection... I solved it by replacing the part of the collection that i sent as a batch with the batch itself, since ToList() and ToEntityCollection both create a new object with the same reference values...

Thanks for putting me in the correct direction guys!